# cp - do not overwrite in makefile

Tags: make, cp

In the makefile for my project, I want it to copy a config file only if the file does not already exist in the destination folder.   At the moment I am using:

```
cp -n
```

However, recently someone has told me that they are getting an "invalid option" error.

My question is:   for a makefile, is there a more compatible method to achieve this than cp -n?

(Note:   cp -u is not what I want, if the file already exists, it should never be replaced even if it is older than the source file.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! [ -e /path/to/foo ]
then
    cp foo /path/to/
fi
```

---

Even better, if this is e.g. a configuration file that might have new, useful options you could:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! [ -e /path/to/foo ]
then
    cp foo /path/to/
else
    cp -f foo /path/to/foo.new
fi
```

so that they still have a copy they can refer to.

Comment: That's a great idea about the .new file, I'll use that - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think your commands from your Makefile are just going to be bash? If so, you can try using the bash if conditional that depends on whether the file exists:

```
if [ -f $FILE ];
then
   #echo "File $FILE exists"
else
   #echo "File $FILE does not exists"
   cp $SRC_FILE $FILE
fi
```

[Bash code from here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/find-out-if-file-exists-with-conditional-expressions.html).

In the event that you discover the Makefile being run in environments where their contents are not evaluated against bash, then you could may be able to use [rsync](http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html) (should be installed on most unixy machines) for the copy operation. Though I just looked through the man page and didn't see a flag for copying only if dest doesn't exist - but I still sort of think that must be accommodated by rsync, just have to find the intended flag to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in a Makefile. Strange "cp -n" worked in the same shell. Would be interesting to know why?!

This is my solution, a bit shorten than if then else

```
test -e folder/requirements.txt || cp -p ../requirements.txt folder/requirements.txt
```